# java interface reference type object can acess other interface memeber in same classe even it not defined inside it?

Tags: java, interface

If I understand this correctly, the reference type determines which member can be accessed (compile time) while the object type determines which member will be used (runtime).

I have class that implements two interfaces. These interfaces are not related (no inheritance relation allowing one to extends member of the other).

One interface when used as reference type of an object can access a method inside the other method.

```
interface Jump { 
    // this one do not define anything
}

interface Climb {
    default void greeting(){
        System.out.println("greeting from Climb interface");
    }
}

public class Test implements Jump, Climb {
    public Test(){
        greeting();
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Climb climb = new Test(); // this is clear that will call default method in Climb
        Jump jump = new Test(); // but why this did compile and print method defined in Jump ?!!!
    }
}
```

The object with reference type `Jump` interface is assumed to access the member in this interface. And the interfaces are not related. What is going on?

Comment: `Jump jump = new Test();` is fine.  What do you see if you code `jump.greeting()`?

Answer (score 1):

Why wouldn't this work?  It doesn't matter what the variable is defined as; its internal implementation will work the same.  You could write

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
  new Test();
}
```

You don't have to assign it to any variable.  There's no typo in that code; it'll work; it'll print `greeting from Climb interface`.

Comment: by the way it mean that no difference betweeen asigning differnce reference variables                           Jump j = new Test();                                                                                                                                       is same as                                                                                                                                                             Climb b ) new Test()                                                                                                                  and this did not make sense

Comment: The difference is that after defining `Jump jump = new Test();`, you can't then write `jump.greeting()`.

Comment: my question is about reference types in which members could acsesses

Comment: Yes.  I think I've answered that: it makes no difference inside the implementation of `Test`, it only makes a difference in what you can do with the variable `jump` after you've initialized it.

Comment: thanks bro, even i did understand well this point but i have another question for (^_^) consern exception : did the throws keyword in methods signature prevent the method from throwing other exception,

Comment: public int test() throws CheckedException {}  here an exception that inherit from exception,if the method throws another checked exception will be prevented, or saying unchecked because checked should be handled or declared

Comment: If you have another question, please ask it separately.